# StatusBar not updating in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, activex, npapi

I'm working with an existing ActiveX control, we have a NPAPI for it, and it works well for the most part in FireFox.  There's an issue with it and I'm completely unfamiliar with NPAPI.  In IE9, the control updates the status bar just fine, but in FireFox v18.0.1 it doesn't seem to update the status bar.  We call NPN_Status() to do this and the call seems fine, it's also being called from the main thread as the documentation suggests it should be.

If I revert to an old version of FireFox like v3, our control updates the status bar, but it seems with v4 and onwards it doesn't.  I installed the Status-4-Evar Add-On in FireFox to make it easier to see the status since v4 there isn't really a status bar, the status just pops up in the corner and then disappears.  I tried updating to the latest xulrunner-sdk v18.0.1 as our control was using an older version, but it hasn't made a difference.

Is there some NPN_XXX call I can make to check if an error has occurred?

In the documentation I see:

> The browser always displays the last status line message it receives, regardless of the message source. Your message is always displayed, but you have no control over how long it stays in the status line before another message replaces it.

I'm only seeing "Done" in the status, is "Done" constantly being sent to the status line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't implemented yet for out-of-process plugins (which were implemented in that time frame).
See [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=554186) and [here](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/e9f39220b8e7/dom/plugins/ipc/PluginModuleChild.cpp#l1249).